# How to replace an umlaut inside a T-SQL function

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, collation

I need to replace umlauts in a function I defined in T-SQL.

My code looks like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[my_function](@s varchar(4000))
RETURNS varchar(4000)
AS
BEGIN
    SET @s = UPPER(@s)
    SET @s = REPLACE(@s, 'Ä', 'AE')

    RETURN @s
END
```

When I input `äpfel` I get `AEPFEL`, which is my expected result,

But when I input `apfel` I also get `AEPFEL`, which is not supposed to happen.

I'm pretty sure that this is a matter of accent-sensitive collation, but I have no idea how to use that with the replace function.

Any input is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify a collation explicitly per string expression:

```
set @s = replace(@s COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN, 'Ä', 'AE')
```

And after this `REPLACE` will take accents into account. Note that you can't put the `COLLATE`on the parameter or the return value, unfortunately, which would be a more obvious solution.

Comment: Thank you! Yeah, I tried putting the collation on the parameter thinking it would be an obvious way to handle this, but that didn't work, of course...

Comment: DECLARE @s as varchar(4000) COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN. DOES NOT HELP. You must expicitly put the collation in the replace function body.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Jeroen Mostert's answer try this code if you need a case sensitive solution.
Note the **CS** = "Case Sensitive" in the used collation.

If you need to handle unicode characters you also should consider using NVARCHAR values.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[my_function](@s varchar(4000))
RETURNS varchar(4000)

AS
BEGIN
SET @s =    REPLACE(
            REPLACE(
            REPLACE(
            REPLACE(
            REPLACE(
            REPLACE(
            REPLACE(@s COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS
            , 'Ä', 'AE')
            , 'Ö', 'OE')
            , 'Ü', 'UE')
            , 'ä', 'ae')
            , 'ö', 'oe')
            , 'ü', 'ue')
            , 'ß', 'ss') 

   RETURN @s

END

SELECT dbo.my_function('AOUSS_aeouss_ÄäÖöÜüß')
-- Result is AOUSS_aeouss_AEaeOEoeUEuess
```